# Подключение яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте.

Я хочу подключить на страницу яндекс карту, но у меня не получается отобразить метку на адресе. Вроде, смотрю на сайте яндекса [Объекты на карте](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/dg/concepts/geoobjects-docpage/), кодов ошибок не дает, но метка не появляется.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```js
var korolev_map;
var myPlacemark;

ymaps.ready(function(){
    korolev_map = new ymaps.Map("korolev", {
        center: [55.932374, 37.837965],
        zoom: 16
    });
    
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.932374, 37.837965], {}, {
        preset: 'twirl#redIcon'
    });

    korolev_map.controls.add(new ymaps.control.ZoomControl());
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.contact-map {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid red; //для наглядности
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="ru">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1" />
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="contacts">
    <ul>
      <li id="korolev" class="contact-map"></li>
      <li class="contact-map"></li>
      <li class="contact-map"></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забыли добавить ваши объекты в вашу карту, используя `korolev_map.geoObjects.add`:

```js
var korolev_map, myPlacemark;

ymaps.ready(function() {
  korolev_map = new ymaps.Map("korolev", {
    center: [55.932374, 37.837965],
    zoom: 16
  });

  myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.932374, 37.837965], {}, {
    preset: 'twirl#redIcon'
  });

  korolev_map.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
  korolev_map.controls.add(new ymaps.control.ZoomControl());
  korolev_map.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom'); 
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.contact-map {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid red; //для наглядности
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<section class="contacts">
  <ul>
    <li id="korolev" class="contact-map"></li>
    <li class="contact-map"></li>
    <li class="contact-map"></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо, только что тоже это нашел!

Comment: Не подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы карта меняла масштаб, только по кнопкам + -, а при скролле не работала?

Comment: @nazarukroman обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо еще раз! И снова нашел ответ в тот момент, когда вы написали мне, спасибо!

Comment: @nazarukroman не за что)